# how to get one foreign key data only one time laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I want get the data of all messages sent to a specific team but I want to get only the first instance of a foreign key and and dont want to repeat it again. For example I want only first row of a specific team id and dont want to repeat the row with same foreign key again. Only want to list data with unique foriegn keys. The following query works well but its repeating the team_id but I want one team id only once. This is the query.

```
  $pages = DB::table('teams')
    ->leftJoin('conversation_teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'conversation_teams.team_id')
    ->select('teams.name','conversation_teams.id','conversation_teams.message_body','conversation_teams.sender_user_id','conversation_teams.receiver_user_id','conversation_teams.created_at','conversation_teams.team_id')
    ->whereIn('conversation_teams.team_id',$my_teams)
    ->orderBy('conversation_teams.created_at', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(12);
```

This is the table structure. 
[table of conversation_teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UbUp.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple group by with min() would help you but you would then have non-aggregated columns in select list which won't let the query to execute.

The workaround is disabling mysql `only_full_group_by option`.

However, without doing it I would take a long shot of adding a join with subquery  :

```
$pages = DB::table('teams')
    ->leftJoin('conversation_teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'conversation_teams.team_id')
    ->join(DB::raw("(SELECT 
      MIN(id) as d_id, team_id as t_id
      FROM conversation_teams
      GROUP BY t_id
      ) as ct_derived"),function($join){
        $join->on("conversation_teams.id","=","ct_derived.d_id");
    })
    ->select('teams.name','conversation_teams.id','conversation_teams.message_body','conversation_teams.sender_user_id','conversation_teams.receiver_user_id','conversation_teams.created_at','conversation_teams.team_id')
    ->whereIn('conversation_teams.team_id',$my_teams)
    ->orderBy('conversation_teams.created_at', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(12);
```

I do not have the table to run query from but what I am trying to do it I am filtering the `conversation_teams` results and taking the first record per team which is what you want if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Thanks sir that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks